# postgresql machine specs performance

Tags: postgresql

is there a way to check performance of a query based on the machine specifications?

if i run a `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` on a postgresql query i can get the plan and see the diferent cost of running said query, but is there any kind of way to see the relationship between the query and the host specifications? i assume a query will run faster on an SSD than on a HDD, but is it possible to get this relationship via postgre?

this seems like a bad question as it seems highly unlikely but I wanted to make sure.

Comment: You should not measure the cost of a query in time units, but in terms of resources used. (memory,disk-I/O,disk-seeks, CPU)

Comment: good point @wildplasser , thanks,  are those resources used query-able? like how can i know the amount of memory, disk i/o, and cpu used?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-explain.html will give you the estimated+actual values for {number,size} of rows, buffer cache usage, (some) work_mem usage. CPU usage is hard to find (but relatively unimportant) , but you have the number of (nested) loops. And there is always top+iostat+vmstat (in unix)

Comment: `I assume a query will run faster on an SSD than on a HDD ...` This is not *always* the case. For instance: I have Postgres running on some Raspberry-Pis, with external SSDs connected via USB. These have a *terrific* seek-time ( <<0.1ms) , but a *terrible* throughput ( < 10MB/s)  And these Pis have *very* little memory ( 500M ... 1 GB, of which about half can be used  to cache disk-contents).

Comment: ahh, I see, thanks @wildplasser, im a complete newbie when it comes to DB stuff, you are a great help, i will keep reading on that sql explain